# tree.com stops after processing 2938 characters

Tags: c#, redirectstandardoutput

I'm just trying to get a full directory list via using tree.com in a c# programm. After it's finished, it should print the results to a file and to a richtextbox.

Now I've got the problem, that tree.com stops after it has processed as many dirs that the outputstream is 2938 characters long but it doesn't close.

Does anyone have an idea why it is like this?

My code:

```
try
            {
                Process proThis = new Process();
                ProcessStartInfo psiThis = new ProcessStartInfo("C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe", "/r tree C:\\");
                psiThis.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                psiThis.UseShellExecute = false;
                proThis.StartInfo = psiThis;
                proThis.Start();
                proThis.WaitForExit();
                if (File.Exists(".\\Dateileselog.zdlog"))
                {
                    File.Delete(".\\Dateileselog.zdlog");
                }

                    string log = proThis.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                    sendMessage(log.Replace("ÃÄÄÄ", "").Replace("³   ", "-->").Replace("ÀÄÄÄ", "").Replace("    ", ""), f1, false);

                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(".\\Dateileselog.zdlog");
                    writer.WriteLine(Base64Encode(log.Replace("ÃÄÄÄ", "").Replace("³   ", "-->").Replace("ÀÄÄÄ", "").Replace("    ", "")));
                    writer.Close();
            }
            catch (Win32Exception w)
            {
                sendMessage(w.Message, f1, false);
                sendMessage(w.ErrorCode.ToString(), f1, false);
                sendMessage(w.NativeErrorCode.ToString(), f1, false);
                sendMessage(w.StackTrace, f1, false);
                sendMessage(w.Source, f1, false);
                Exception e = w.GetBaseException();
                sendMessage(e.Message, f1, false);
            }
```

Thanks in advance!

Filip Zocktan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
proThis.WaitForExit();
```

The output is placed in a limited sized buffer. When the buffer is full, trying to write into the buffer will block the running process until you read from the buffer, allowing further input into the buffer.

Using `ReadToEnd()` already ensures you get all output text and it will only return when the other process has stopped.